# How to show input data in alert window by button click using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

This is the code of the WebForm, When I debug the page and insert a break point at the   `$scope.ShowAlert = function(){` line, the browser doesn't reach the inner code.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="container">

    <div class="row" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">

        <input type="text" ng-model="FName" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="Lname" />

        <input type="button" value="Show Alert Message" ng-clicl="ShowAlert()" />

    </div>

</div>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
    app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $window){
        $scope.ShowAlert = function(){
            $window.alert("Hello" + $scope.Fname + " " + $scope.Lname);
        }

    });


</script>
```

Comment: Did you run it on internet explorer ?

Comment: there is a typo here ng-clicl should be ng-click

Comment: I am running the code in Chrome

Comment: Is there nay wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

it is just a typo !!!

change ng-clicl to ng-click ;-)

Comment: It really to childish of me to make such a silly mistake

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-clicl="ShowAlert()"
```

Try  change to ng-click. 
If still not working, instead of `$window.alert(...)`use only `alert(...)`

Comment: Now I have make some changes in the code

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
        app.controller('MyController', function ($scope){
            $scope.ShowAlert = function () {
                if ($scope.Fname == "")
                {
                   alert("Please Enter Fisrt Name");
                }
                if ($scope.Lname == " ")
                {
                   alert("Please Enter Your Last Name");
                }
                alert("Hello" + $scope.Fname + " " + $scope.Lname);
            }
        
        });

Comment: After this changes when I enter the First and Last name and click on the Button.

Alert windows is showing as Helloundefinehussain

I have enter Sajjad in Fname and Hussain Lname

Comment: thats can be, becouse in html code you have FName, and in js script you have Fname. More typo! :)